# trouble inserting PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

okay so I just started on a project and Im creating the membership part of the site I have 2 classes so far one for database other for managing users here they are:

```
class dbConnect
{
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = 'todo';
    public $db_user= 'root';
    public $db_pass = 'pass';
    public $db_host = '127.0.0.1';

    function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname = $this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the users class

```
class ManageUsers
{
    public $link;

    function __construct()
    {
        $db_connection = new dbConnect();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($username,$pass,$ip_adress,$time,$date)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, ip_adress, time, date_joined) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($username,$pass,$ip_adress,$time,$date);
        $query->execute($values);
        $counts = $query->rowCount();
        return $counts;
    }
}

$users = new ManageUsers();
echo $registered = $users->registerUsers('bob','marley','127.0.0.1','12:00','29-02-2012');
```

Now the issue that I'm having is that it is not inserting the data into the database I've triple checked and the tables in the database match the query so maybe its something in the syntax. The function runs with no errors and it returns zero instead of 1. Well thanks for the help take it easy

Comment: Are you calling both classes from two seperate files, or are both classes inside the same file?

Comment: separate but im including the dbconnect class in the manageusers class

Comment: @Fred-ii-  include_once 'class.db.php';

Comment: @Fred-ii-  its returning a result of zero when i run it so it working properly

Comment: take a look in the log file and/or echo the last db error with `$query->errorInfo()`

Comment: Another guy that is reinventing the wheel.
Please prefer libraries/framework to work with your datebase, you will get less low-level problems ;-)

When you're including another class, you may want it required, in this case, use require_once 'path/to/your/file.php'

Comment: @niyou no erros are being logged I just deleted my whole log file and tried the errorInfo function and both blank

Comment: If you delete the log/access files, you need to reboot your server. Also, what is the datatype for `time` and `date_joined` columns?

Comment: @hjpotter92 for testing purposes i just have them as varchar since everything i am adding is a string

Comment: @hjpotter92 ive added my error log file

Comment: @niyou i added my error log file

Comment: i meant the webserver logfile. the db logfile is useless if it logs nothing

Comment: In your locale, is `29-02-2012` a valid date format? I realize 2012 was a leap year, but is the order `dd-mm-yyyy` correct? And Bob Marley's birthday was February 6... but I don't think *that* is your problem...

Comment: @Floris I dont save birthdays but thanks for the info lol and the date format doesn't really matter since its a string

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I would echo a message to the screen (not just return the error message instead of the connection) if there's a problem connecting to the database. Are you sure database name etc are valid ? Have you tried making a simple script (instead of multiple function calls) that inserts data - just for test purposes? Make something simple work first, then add complexity - it is often a good strategy.

Comment: Curious to know what you needed to do to fix your code. I tried fixing it for an hour last night, with no success. @user3051232

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added my updated code as an answer

Comment: Thanks, am glad to know that you managed to fix your code. I happen to notice that someone took your code and made it as another question, not long ago. I saw that it was 99% the same. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/q/21169243/1415724 @user3051232 or is that you? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha that's pretty funny I guess I can answer his question and get a check mark lol

Comment: Sure, why not? LOL! I `+1` for your answer by the way. It's always worth giving credit where credit is due, when someone fixes their code. Classes can be quite difficult at times and I'm rather new to learning them, but it's coming along slowly but surely. @user3051232 Yet, the answer given on the other question, was actually just that, the DB connection. It worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm also relatively new to OOP that's why I'm creating this website for personal training in OOP. I've done a few small projects in OOP and I love it after OOP clicks in a way it's actually easier than procedural code. This however is going to be  big website so It'll be a real test to my new OOP skills

Comment: Using classes for a big website is definitely worth doing, since they handle most of the grunt work. I'm good with functions, but OOP/classes tend to mix me up a bit. I just need to further analyze them and get a better feel. @user3051232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several obvious problems:

- Your problem is that you did not configure your PDO driver properly

It's a good practice to halt execution when SQL command/query fails. In order to activate it, you'd define corresponding driver option `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

- Your `dbConnect` class does not make sense

First of all, you're connecting to `MySQL` server and therefore it would be much better to indicate it somehow. And since your `dbConnect` is a logical part of database connection, [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) isn't the way to go. Instead that class should be extended (as it satisfies `is-a` relationship)

So, you can write a class that would MySQL-PDO specific, that could look like this:

```
class MySQL_PDO extends PDO
{
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $params['host'];

        if (isset($params['dbname'])) {
            $dsn .= ';dbname=' . $params['dbname'];
        }

        $options = array(
            parent::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8',
            parent::ATTR_ERRMODE            => parent::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            parent::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            parent::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => parent::FETCH_ASSOC,
        );

        parent::__construct($dsn, $params['username'], $params['password'], $options);
    }
}
```

And you can initialize it like

```
$db_options = array(
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'dbname'   => 'todo'
);

$pdo_driver = new MySQL_PDO($db_options);
```

Your `ManageUsers` is actually an implementation of the [DataMapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern), that should be  properly taking advantage of [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Also, note that `time` is a reserved word in MySQL, and therefore you'd better sticking with back-ticks everywhere.

```
class UserMapper
{
   protected $pdo;

   public function __construct($pdo)
   {
      $this->pdo = $pdo;
   }

   public function insert($username, $password, $ip_adress, $time, $date_joined)
   {
       $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `ip_adress`, `time`, `date_joined`) VALUES (:username, :password, :ip_adress, :time)"

       $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
       return $stmt->execute(array(
           ':username'   => $username,
           ':password'   => $password,
           ':ip_adress'  => $ip_adress,
           ':date_joined'=> $date_joined
       ));
   }
}
```

And you finally, you can use it all, just like:

```
$mapper = new UserMapper($pdo_driver);
$mapper->insert('foo', .....);
```

Comment: Thanks man I made a few changes to my code thanks to your advice and it works

Answer (score 1):

here is the working code

```
class dbConnect
{
  protected $db_conn;
  public $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
  public $db_user = 'root';
  public $db_pass = 'roadmin';
  public $db_name = 'todo';

  public function connect()
  {
    try
    {
      $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
      return $this->db_conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the manage users class

```
include_once('class.db.php');

class ManageUsers
{
  public $link;

  function __construct()
  {
    $db_connection = new dbConnect();
    $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
    return $this->link;
  }

  function registerUsers($username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date)
  {
    $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username,email, password, ip_adress, date_joined)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $values = [$username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date];
    $query->execute($values);
    $confirm = $query->rowCount();
    return $confirm;
  }

  function loginUser
}

$test = new ManageUsers();
echo $test->registerUsers('bob','a@a.com','lol','127.0.0.1','2012');
```