# trouble with PDO object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so I am creating a membership website so far I only have 2 classes a class for connecting got the database and a class to manage users

here is the class for the database:

```
class dbConnect
{
  protected $db_conn;
  public $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
  public $db_user = 'root';
  public $db_pass = '';
  public $db_name = 'db';

  public function connect()
  {
    try
    {
      $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
      return $this->db_conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the users class it only has 1 method I just started this project

```
class ManageUsers
{
  public $link;

  function __construct()
  {
    $db_connection = new dbConnect();
    $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
    return $this->link;
  }

  function registerUsers($username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date)
  {
    $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username,email,password,ip_adress,date_joined) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $values = [$username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date];
    $query->execute($values);
    $confirm = $query->rowCount();
    return $confirm;
  }
}
```

Now I'm just running a test object to see if all this s functioning

```
$test = new ManageUsers();
echo $test->registerUsers('bob','a@a.com','lol','127.0.0.1','2012');
```

now I am getting the error that I am calling the prepare statement to a non object. Which to be honest I don't understand since I creating the object in the construct method. well any advice helps Thanks!

Comment: take out return $this->link; and see if this works ?

Comment: You're returning `$this->link` in your constructor - you don't need to do that, and I suspect that might be why you're getting the problem.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thank you but unfortunately it did not fix it

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks but no good

Comment: Hmm so can you make sure that the connect code inside try block is setting the connection object ?

Comment: Are you sure your constructor is getting called?

Comment: @SenorAmor the construct method gets called automatically

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty how could I be able to check that?

Comment: I understand it's **supposed** to get called automatically, but you should verify that it actually **is**.

Comment: print_r($this->db_conn); before returning that in the connect() function

Comment: @andrewsi is correct, you should never use `return` in a constructor, because it will be ignored. The return value from `new dbConnect` is *always* the dbConnect object. In your code, if the PDO connection fails, you try to return the exception message, but this will be lost. So you've effectively just discarded the exception, and obscured any way of detecting an error.

Answer (score 3):

I think PDO object is invalid, because you are using double quotes with method/property of object, in that case you need use complex string notation(`"{$object->property}"`) or join strings with `.` (a dot)

[about php strings](https://www.php.net/language.types.string.php)

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
```

change to:

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a really similar script from you here it is

```
class dbConnect
{
  protected $db_conn;
  public $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
  public $db_user = 'root';
  public $db_pass = 'roadmin';
  public $db_name = 'todo';

  public function connect()
  {
    try
    {
      $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
      return $this->db_conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

}

class ManageUsers
{
  public $link;

  function __construct()
  {
    $db_connection = new dbConnect();
    $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
    return $this->link;
  }

  function registerUsers($username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date)
  {
    $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (username,email, password, ip_adress, date_joined)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $values = [$username,$email,$password,$ip_adress,$date];
    $query->execute($values);
    $confirm = $query->rowCount();
    return $confirm;
  }

  function loginUser()
  {

  }
}

$test = new ManageUsers();
echo $test->registerUsers('bob','a@a.com','lol','127.0.0.1','2012');
```

Comment: So, what did you fix?  What's different about the code you posted?